# Date of tradingview lightweight chart showing a wrong date of only 1/1/1970

Tags: javascript, php, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

Please I need help me with tradingview js chart customization. I am having a serious issue with the chart.
Chart is not showing accurate date pull from the database into the chart
[image]

The picture above is the chart showing the accurate date of the data provided

[image]

Data pulled from the database gives the wrong date thereby gives a wrong chart.
How can I correct the chart date

```
    var investment_charts = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('investment_charts'), {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        priceScale: {
            scaleMargins: {
                top: 0.2,
                bottom: 0.2,
            },
        position: 'left',
            borderVisible: true,
        },
        timeScale: {
            borderVisible: false,
        },
        grid: {
            horzLines: {
                color: '#eee',
            },
            vertLines: {
                color: '#ffffff',
            },
        },
        crosshair: {
                horzLine: {
                visible: false,
                labelVisible: false
            },
            vertLine: {
                visible: true,
                style: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: 'rgba(32, 38, 46, 0.1)',
                labelVisible: false,
            }
        },
    });

    // chart.resize(320, 250);
    var series = investment_charts.addAreaSeries({  
        topColor: 'rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.2)', 
        bottomColor: 'rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.0)',
        lineColor: 'rgba(0, 120, 255, 1)',
        lineWidth: 3
    });

    series.setData([
        <?php
        foreach($user->historychart as $key=>$value){
            if($value->investment_amount != null){
                echo '{ time:'.$value->created_at->format('Y-m-d').', value:'. $value->investment_amount.'},';
            }
        }
        ?>

    ]);

    function businessDayToString(businessDay) {
        return new Date(Date.UTC(businessDay.year, businessDay.month - 1, businessDay.day, 0, 0, 0)).toLocaleDateString();
    }

    var toolTipWidth    = 96;
    var toolTipHeight   = 40;
    var toolTipMargin   = 15;
    var priceScaleWidth = 10;

    var toolTip = document.createElement('div');
    toolTip.className = 'floating-tooltip-1';
    document.getElementById('investment_charts').appendChild(toolTip);

    // update tooltip
    investment_charts.subscribeCrosshairMove(function(param) {
        if (!param.time || param.point.x < 0 || param.point.x > width || param.point.y < 0 || param.point.y > height) {
            toolTip.style.display = 'none';
            return;
        }

        var dateStr = LightweightCharts.isBusinessDay(param.time)
            ? businessDayToString(param.time)
            : new Date(param.time * 1000).toLocaleDateString();

        toolTip.style.display = 'block';
        var price = param.seriesPrices.get(series);
        toolTip.innerHTML = '<div style="color: rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.9)">⬤ Naira</div>' +
            '<div style="font-size: 24px; margin: 4px 0px; color: #20262E">' + (Math.round(price * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + '</div>' +
            '<div>' + dateStr + '</div>';

        var left = param.point.x;


        if (left > width - toolTipWidth - toolTipMargin) {
            left = width - toolTipWidth;
        } else if (left < toolTipWidth / 2) {
        left = priceScaleWidth;
    }

        toolTip.style.left = left + 'px';
        toolTip.style.top = 80 + 'px';
    });








    var charts = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById('charts'), {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        priceScale: {
            scaleMargins: {
                top: 0.2,
                bottom: 0.2,
            },
        position: 'left',
            borderVisible: true,
        },
        timeScale: {
            borderVisible: false,
        },
        grid: {
            horzLines: {
                color: '#eee',
            },
            vertLines: {
                color: '#ffffff',
            },
        },
        crosshair: {
                horzLine: {
                visible: false,
                labelVisible: false
            },
            vertLine: {
                visible: true,
                style: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: 'rgba(32, 38, 46, 0.1)',
                labelVisible: false,
            }
        },
    });

    // chart.resize(320, 250);
    var seriesa = charts.addAreaSeries({    
        topColor: 'rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.2)', 
        bottomColor: 'rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.0)',
        lineColor: 'rgba(0, 120, 255, 1)',
        lineWidth: 3
    });

    seriesa.setData([
         <?php
        foreach($user->historychart as $key=>$value){
            if($value->daily_profit != null){
                echo '{ time:'.$value->created_at->format('Y-m-d').', value:'. $value->daily_profit.'},';
            }
        }
        ?>

    ]);

    function businessDayToString1(businessDay) {
        return new Date(Date.UTC(businessDay.year, businessDay.month - 1, businessDay.day, 0, 0, 0)).toLocaleDateString();
    }

    var toolTipWidth1    = 96;
    var toolTipHeight1   = 40;
    var toolTipMargin1   = 15;
    var priceScaleWidth1 = 10;

    var toolTip1 = document.createElement('div');
    toolTip1.className = 'floating-tooltip-2';
    document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(toolTip1);

    // update tooltip
    charts.subscribeCrosshairMove(function(param) {
        if (!param.time || param.point.x < 0 || param.point.x > width || param.point.y < 0 || param.point.y > height) {
            toolTip1.style.display = 'none';
            return;
        }

        var dateStr = LightweightCharts.isBusinessDay(param.time)
            ? businessDayToString1(param.time)
            : new Date(param.time * 1000).toLocaleDateString();

        toolTip1.style.display = 'block';
        var price = param.seriesPrices.get(seriesa);
        toolTip1.innerHTML = '<div style="color: rgba(0, 120, 255, 0.9)">⬤ Naira</div>' +
            '<div style="font-size: 24px; margin: 4px 0px; color: #20262E">' + (Math.round(price * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + '</div>' +
            '<div>' + dateStr + '</div>';

        var left = param.point.x;


        if (left > width - toolTipWidth1 - toolTipMargin1) {
            left = width - toolTipWidth1;
        } else if (left < toolTipWidth1 / 2) {
        left = priceScaleWidth1;
    }

        toolTip1.style.left = left + 'px';
        toolTip1.style.top = 80 + 'px';
    });
```

Where I guess the issue comes from is the point where I call the loop of the data from the database but I don't know exactly why it's showing the wrong dates.

```
<?php
    foreach($user->historychart as $key=>$value){
        if($value->investment_amount != null){
            echo '{ time:'.$value->created_at->format('Y-m-d').', value:'. $value->investment_amount.'},';
        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: I just re-edited the question and the image. The chart is not showing the correct date of the record.

Comment: Ok. Let me do that.

Comment: @Teemu This question is not Closed, please. The question is different from the one suggested.

Comment: What exactly format is in `$value->created_at->format('Y-m-d')` code? I'm not familiar with PHP, but there might be an issue.

Comment: @timocov the format above is 2019-12-15

Comment: Is it possible to get what the page actually is? I meant after all processing with your server, what the browser get.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing the date into a double quote to turn it into a string.

```
<?php
foreach($user->historychart as $key=>$value){
    if($value->investment_amount != null){
        echo '{ time:"'.$value->created_at->format('Y-m-d').'", value:'. $value->investment_amount.'},';
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

for me, I change the code from normal date to timestamp date

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
timenow = str(now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))                    
        
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timenow, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
timestamp = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date)
linechart = {
    "time" : timestamp,
    "value" : row[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get timestamp from Binance for exemple you have to /1000

The 01/01/1970 is the date of the first timestamp 0000000000, it's returned when your timestamp is too big/wrong